# How to count the number of elements with a particular class name?

Tags: nightwatch.js

How do I count the number of elements with a particular class name using nightwatch?

For example, I want to count the number of elements with class name "sample" on the page and check that the number if greater than 8. How can I do that using nightwatch?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your page includes this markup:

```html
<ul id="names">
    <li>Stephanie</li>
    <li>Luke</li>
    <li>Marina</li>
</ul>
```

You could do something like this:

```js
module.exports = {
    'Example test': browser => {
        browser.url(browser.launchUrl);
        browser.elements('css selector', '#names li', result => {
            const numElements = result.value.length;
            console.log(numElements);
        });
    }
}
```

Just bear in mind that you can't use `numElements` outside of that callback. Returning it from the callback won't help: `browser.elements` ignores the return value. Initializing `numElements` before the callback and setting its value *inside* the callback won't help either: the callback might be run much later.

If you really need to use that value outside of the callback, you'll need to use a `Promise`:

```js
module.exports = {
    'Example test': browser => {
        browser.url(browser.launchUrl);

        const numElementsPromise = new Promise(resolve => {
            browser.elements('css selector', '#names li', result => {
                resolve(result.value.length);
            });
        });

        numElementsPromise.then(numElements => {
            console.log(numElements);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use getEls.

```
client.getEls('.sample', function(collection) {
            // set the variable to be that collection's length      
            elementCount = collection.length;   
            // use the conditional for to check your collections length
            if(collection.length > 8){
                 // log the count of elements to the terminal
                 console.log("Yes. There were " + elementCount + "elements")
                // or do other things here
            }
            else{
                 // log the count of elements to the terminal
                 console.log("There were " + elementCount + "elements")
            }
            return;     
        });
```

Comment: How do I assert that the length is greater than 6?

Comment: How do I throw an error if the length is not greater than 6?

Comment: Did you edit the question? I think I answered your initial question, but you changed it. That's not good form.

Comment: Updated for you, but you really ought to know how to do that.

Comment: @QualiT could you link to the docs ? I see no such method as `getEls()` in the [API](http://nightwatchjs.org/api/#elements).

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/testarmada-magellan-nightwatch. Do a find on getEls( in your Nightwatch root and you can see the method yourself, review it's internals. There should be getEls.js in the source.

Answer (score 0):

using a css or Xpath selector.
here you go:

```
// use a css or Xpath selector 
client.elements(selector ,function(result) {
  return result.value.length;

});
```

Comment: this is a "code only" answer - please add some more detail about how this solves it for future readers with questions to nightwatch that do not have your level of expertiese in js or nightwatch. You could use the questions given example of elements of classname "sample" and the check with  8 on a small html page wich you add to your answer as well.