# How to I get a count of a selector and pass into a variable I can use later?

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I am looking to get a row count of items returned so I can later add a filter to the list.  Then I will assert that the filtered list number is less than the total number.

I have tried a number of .perform and .execute arrangements and continue to get undefined errors.

```
module.exports = {
    'Verify rows': function (browser) {
        var value_id = 0;
        browser
            .url(browser.launchUrl)
            .waitForElementVisible('body', 20000)
            .pause(4000)
            .verify.visible('div:nth-of-type(2) > form > div > div > div > div')
            .assert.gdGreater('.offering-item-container', 0)
            .execute(function () {
                value_id = document.querySelectorAll('.offering-item-container').length;
            })
            .click('#IsGuaranteedToRun')
            .pause(4000)
            .assert.gdLess('#IsGuaranteedToRun', value_id)
    }

};
```

Comment: what is the error you're getting?

Comment: Along with that error, can you include your HTML as well? Simply looking at this partial script doesn't tell us much.

Comment: I'm looking to get a count of the 'offering-item-container' divs.
<div id="offering-list-outer-container" class="offering-list-outer-container">
        <div class="offering-item-container" data-offeringid="669931" >
            <!--items are loaded dynamicaly-->
        </div>
        <div class="offering-item-container" data-offeringid="849412">
            <!--items are loaded dynamicaly-->
        </div>
        <div class="offering-item-container" data-offeringid="861290">
            <!--items are loaded dynamicaly-->
        </div>
</div>

Comment: The error is:
Testing if element <#IsGuaranteedToRun> is less than count: 0 in 1000 ms. - expected "0" but got: "1"

The total count of rows is 70, not zero, so the value of value_id is not coming outside of the function.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36047758/how-to-count-the-number-of-elements-with-a-particular-class-name) that helped point me in the right direction.  Then I had to include the next steps within the callback.

```
module.exports = {
    'Verify rows': function (browser) {
        var value_id = 0;
        browser
            .url(browser.launchUrl)
            .waitForElementVisible('body', 20000)
            .pause(4000);
            const numElementsPromise = new Promise(resolve => {
                browser.elements('css selector', '.offering-item-container', result => {
                    resolve(result.value.length);
                });
            });

        numElementsPromise.then(result => {
            value_id = result;
            browser
                .pause(4000)
                .verify.visible('div:nth-of-type(2) > form > div > div > div > div')
                .assert.gdGreater('.offering-item-container', 0)
                .click('#IsGuaranteedToRun')
                .pause(4000)
                .assert.gdLess('.offering-item-container', value_id)
                .click('#IsGuaranteedToRun')
                .assert.gdEquals('.offering-item-container', value_id);
        });
  }
```

};